# Outlook from field always reverts to default reply address

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange-2010

I have two email addresses with different domains on one exchange account. I need to be able to send from both addresses but when changing the from field it always reverts to the default email address.

Can this be changed without having two mailboxes?

This is in Outlook 2013 with an Exchange 2010 mailbox. Although some users use Outlook 2010 and will require the same thing.

Comment: You said *"Although some users use Outlook 2010 and will require the same thing"*. Does that mean Outlook 2010 has the same problem or are you just assuming.

Comment: @CharlieRB - Yes, it is definitely the same in 2010.